# Android - SMS - intent-filters priority listing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-intent

I was wondering if it is possible to find a list that includes all the receivers associated to a certain action.

For example I have the following receiver that executes everytime that an SMS is received:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="101">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

So with the priority="101" it´s executed even before than the default message service in Android.

I would like to find all the intent-filter associated to a certail action, in this case "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"

I tried to get into /data/data/com.android.provider.telephony/databases but no info is stored in ther.

It would be great if anybody could tell me where can I find that info, and even if it is possible.

Regards,

Pablo

Answer (score 2):

Use `PackageManager` and [`queryBroadcastReceivers()`](http://goo.gl/SZqdo) to find out all of the `BroadcastReceivers` that will respond to a given `Intent`. In your case, you would create an `SMS_RECEIVED` `Intent`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but would it be possible to get that info directly recovering the information from a .db file o even an xml. That has to be stored somewhere.

Probably I´ll develop a tool to do that in the near future but know i need it ASAP :(

Comment: @pablora: "get that info directly recovering the information from a .db file o even an xml" -- no. "That has to be stored somewhere" -- it is in the manifests of each application, which you cannot access.