# Android: SMS-app available in "Choose which app to open this with"-dialog

Tags: android, sms, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am developing an SMS application. How do I make the app available in the "Choose which app to open this with" dialog?

Thanks,
Martin

/EDIT: I think you just misunderstood me.

I don't want to write a sms with my app, I want that others can write sms using my app and that my app is listed in the "Choose which app to open this with" dialog when you pick up sending a sms in the contact list.

An extract from my Application Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_MESSAGING" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Adding the category "APP_MESSAGING" just did not solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done with intent filters.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Look under "intent resolution" and "intent filters"

Comment: I think you misunderstood me:

I dont want to open another app to write a sms, I want that my app is choosable to write a sms with it.

Comment: The Intent filter goes in the Manifest of the app which advertises that one of its components has the capability to handle the intent.  So you need to add an appropriate intent filter to get yourself on the menu.

Comment: It looks like you added some intent filters to the manifest but it may not be the right one.  Check this answer for the way to query what intents you need to be catching.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447079/andoird-sms-intent-filters-priority-listing

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had a similar problem. This is how I fixed it. This is how I declared my activity in the manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.sms.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <data android:scheme="sms" />
              <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this two intent filters to your main activity,
your app will available in SMS App List

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.MainAcitivty"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

       <!--add these intent filters to your app-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/mms"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```